# How to test which iterative combinatorics & permutation calculator is the most efficient?

Tags: r, unit-testing, testing, combinations, combinatorics

I am trying to test which of the two functions is faster at computing the sum of combinations or permutations.

UPDATE: `microbenchmark` package seems to be the answer to my original question, but I'd like to know why the switches in `combo_beast` are cheaper than `combo_unicorn`...

```
> microbenchmark(combo_beast(5,'yes','yes'))
Unit: microseconds
                         expr   min    lq    mean median    uq    max neval
 combo_beast(5, "yes", "yes") 8.019 8.354 9.94767  8.688 9.022 32.412   100
> microbenchmark(combo_unicorn(5,'yes','yes'))
Unit: microseconds
                           expr   min    lq     mean median    uq    max neval
 combo_unicorn(5, "yes", "yes") 8.354 8.688 10.63269  9.022 9.357 41.768   100
```

The first function uses nested switches:

```
combo_beast <- function(n, order, rep){
  switch(order,
         yes = switch(rep,
                      yes = {
                        y <- 0
                        for(i in 1:n){
                          x <- n^i
                          y <- x + y}
                        return(y)
                      },
                      no = {
                        y <- 0
                        for(i in 1:n){
                          x <- factorial(n + i - 1)/(factorial(i)*factorial(n-1))  
                          y <- x + y}
                        return(y)
                      }
                     ),
         no = switch(rep,
                     yes = {
                        y <- 0
                        for(i in 1:n){
                          x <- factorial(n)/(factorial(n - i))  
                          y <- x + y}
                        return(y)
                      },
                      no = {
                        y <- 0
                        for(i in 1:n){
                          x <- factorial(n)/(factorial(n-i)*factorial(i))
                          y <- x + y}
                        return(y)
                      }
                     )
  )
}
```

The second function utilizes the if/else if approach:

```
combo_unicorn <- function(n, order, rep){
  if(order == 'yes' & rep == 'yes'){
    y <- 0
    for(i in 1:n){
      x <- n^i
      y <- x + y}
    return(y)
  } else if (order == 'yes' & rep == 'no'){
    y <- 0
    for(i in 1:n){
      x <- factorial(n + i - 1)/(factorial(i)*factorial(n-1))  
      y <- x + y}
    return(y)
  } else if (order == 'no' & rep == 'no'){
    y <- 0
    for(i in 1:n){
      x <- factorial(n)/(factorial(n-i)*factorial(i))
      y <- x + y}
    return(y)
  } else {
    y <- 0
    for(i in 1:n){
      x <- factorial(n)/(factorial(n - i))  
      y <- x + y}
    return(y)
  }
}
```

I have tried putting `ptm <- proc.time()` at the start of either function and `proc.time() - ptm` at the end, but it keeps returning 0s no matter how large I make `n`.

Comment: try the microbenchmark package

Comment: @RichardTelford awesome, thank you.  any idea of the answer to my update, above?

Comment: No idea, but check whether the result is consistent for  (order == 'no' & rep == 'no') etc.

Comment: Ah, I see.  So should I move the 'no' and 'yes' combos to match positionally within each parent function if I want to do a sound test? @RichardTelford

Comment: Might not make any difference, but you cannot conclude one is faster than the other without exploring more of the parameter space.